# How to SUM all results

Tags: sql, mysql, sum

This is my query to get all the weightages:

```
SELECT weightage FROM r_job_skill WHERE id_job = ? AND gdskill = 1
```

I am getting results like this:

```
weightage
10
20
50
```

I want to calculate the sum of all these results how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(weightage) 
FROM r_job_skill 
WHERE id_job = ? 
AND gdskill = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(weightage) 
FROM r_job_skill 
WHERE id_job = ? 
AND gdskill = 1;
```

[see example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eChI3.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sum()` mysql function to calculate sum of column

your code look like this

```
SELECT sum(weightage) as total FROM r_job_skill WHERE id_job = ? AND gdskill = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(weightage) FROM (SELECT weightage FROM r_job_skill WHERE id_job = ? AND gdskill = 1");
```